# "this" changes value on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype-programming

If I have the following code:

```
function Something() {
    this.randomElement = $("#element");
}

Something.prototype = {

    functionOne: function() {
        console.log("hello");
    },

    functionTwo: function() {
        this.randomElement.click(function(e) {
            this.functionOne(); //this becomes pointed at randomElement
        });
    }
}
```

How can I write this in a clean way where I wouldn't have to use `Something.prototype.functionOne()` to replace `this.functionOne()` inside of functionTwo? Since the click event changes the value of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `this` is bound to the item that is clicked. You need to use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

```
this.randomElement.click( this.functionOne.bind(this) );
```

or jQuery's [proxy](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/).

```
this.randomElement.click( $.proxy(this.functionOne, this) );
```